# How can i get an unlimited install link from my google developer account without making my app public?

Tags: android, google-play-services

I want to upload my app on play store but make it visible only through a sharable link. That is, i don't want my app to be public to anyone visiting me play account but **only to people who have specific link to my different apps.**

Comment: This is not a stack Overflow Question, but for this case you can use internal test and give certain People or better their Google Emails Access to this test

Comment: Dominik Wuttke Thanks for the tip, but Internal testind is limited to 100 user only and the link is valid just for 60 days. I need unlimited tester and time.